# android:RecyclerView smoothScrollToPosition estimates destination position imprecisely

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollto

I have horizontal `RecyclerView` which size is slightly wider then item width inside it:

[image]

When user stops scrolling I'd like `RecyclerView` aligns its position to a nearest item.Here is my logic(initialization):

```
list=(RecyclerView) this.getView().findViewById(R.id.selector_list);
list.setHasFixedSize(true);
llm= new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext(), OrientationHelper.HORIZONTAL,false);
list.setLayoutManager(llm);
    scrollListener=new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if (newState==AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                float imgWidth= (((ImagePreviewView) getView()).getImageHeight()* AppModel.IMAGE_ASPECT_RATIO);
                final int nImg=Math.round((list.computeHorizontalScrollOffset()/imgWidth));
                //img=1;
                Log.d("list","listener removed:"+nImg);
                list.removeOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
                //do align
                list.smoothScrollToPosition(nImg);
            }
        }
    };
    //list.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
    list.setOnTouchListener(this);
    list.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    list.setItemViewCacheSize(0);
    adapter =new PreviewAdapter(this.getContext());
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    if (data!=null)
        adapter.setData(data);
```

Add scroll listener when user starts scrolling

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        Log.d("list","listener added");
        list.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.rhyboo.net.puzzle.selector.layouts.PreviewImage xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/preloader"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
  </com.rhyboo.net.puzzle.selector.layouts.PreviewImage>
```

Item class(related part):

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    int desiredWidth= (int) (heightSize* AppModel.IMAGE_ASPECT_RATIO);
    widthMeasureSpec=MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(desiredWidth,MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

The problem is sometimes smoothScrollToPosition aligns its position not precisely:
[image]

If I scroll further it backs to normal:
[image]
I can see same behavior even If I always scroll to a fixed position `list.smoothScrollToPosition(1);`
Looks like destination position of scrollTo depends on current scroll position which is nonsense.

Comment: simply use `LinearSnapHelper`

Comment: @pskink.Thanks dude.That was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: sure, your welcome